Playwright angular application : When i trying to save click button getting invalid form / Reference Error: page is not defined
click events are correctly triggering other actions but encountering issues specifically with the save button resulting in an "invalid form" message
async fillCustomerForm(customerData) {
this.logger.info('Filling customer details');
    try {
        // Wait for the file input element to be visible
        await this.page.waitForSelector("#fileInput");

        // Set the file input (assuming the file path is correct)
        await this.page.setInputFiles("#fileInput", "C:\\Users\\sathishd\\Downloads\\EtihadAirways.jpg");
        await this.page.waitForTimeout(2000);

        // Fill in the form inputs and select dropdown options
        await this.page.fill('(//input[@id="organizationName"])[1]', customerData.customerName);
        await this.page.getByLabel('Short Name').click();
        await this.page.getByLabel('Short Name').fill('SPR');
       // await this.page.fill("(//input[@id='shortName'])[1]", customerData.shortName);
        await this.page.fill("(//input[@id='shortName'])[2]", customerData.customerECode);
        await this.page.selectOption("(//select[@id='opucode dropdown-toggle'])[2]", customerData.customerType);
        await this.page.waitForTimeout(2000);
        await this.page.fill("(//input[@type='text'])[5]", customerData.ICAO);
        await this.page.fill("(//input[@type='text'])[6]", customerData.IATA);
        await this.page.waitForTimeout(2000);

        // Click on the date picker input and set the date
        await this.page.click('#ej2-datepicker_0 input');
        await this.page.fill("(//input[@id='ej2-datepicker_0_input'])[1]", customerData.InductionDate);

        // Select user-defined category from a dropdown
        await this.page.selectOption("(//select[@id='opucode dropdown-toggle'])[3]", customerData.userdefinedCategory);
        await this.page.waitForTimeout(2000);

        **try {
            // Wait for the save button to be visible and clickable
            
            await this.page.waitForSelector('button:has-text("Save")', { visible: true, timeout: 5000 });
            
            // Click the save button
            //await this.page.click('button:has-text("Save")');
            await this.page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Save' }).first().click({ force: true });
           // await page.getByRole('button').click({ force: true });
            this.logger.info('Save button clicked successfully');
        } catch (error) {
            this.logger.error(`Error clicking save button: ${error}`);**
        
            // Attempt to capture a screenshot for debugging
            try {
                const screenshotPath = 'C:/sathish/AiDocx_Automation_Plywrt02/screenshot/save_button_error.png';
                await this.page.screenshot({ path: screenshotPath });
                this.logger.info(`Screenshot captured: ${screenshotPath}`);
            } catch (screenshotError) {
                this.logger.error(`Error capturing screenshot: ${screenshotError}`);
            }
        }


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

getting 'invalid form' error when I'm trying click save button option in automate web application

Please share the site you're running this on and a [mcve]. Multiple bad practices here: avoid xpath, avoid try/catch conditions in tests, and don't use timeouts--use real, event-driven predicates like locator actionability (preferred), network requests, or waitForFunctions.
